# Почему перестал работать онлайн?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Делаю онлайн игру, в которой до определенного момента нормально работал онлайн(то есть, заходя со второй вкладки, появлялся второй пользователь и т.д). Но теперь - нет. Этот определенный момент - изменение кода отрисовки игрока(понял я это, вернув старый код). Вот и вопрос - что в новом коду мешает отрисовывать двух игроков?
Новый код

```
function draw()
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(player.positionX, player.positionY, player.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    // Рисование лицевой части круга с учетом угла
    context.save();
    context.translate(player.positionX, player.positionY);
    context.rotate(player.angle);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, player.radius, -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    context.restore();
}
function update()
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    draw();

}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Старый

```
//    context.beginPath();
// context.arc(player.positionX,  player.positionY, player.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
// context.fillStyle = "red";
// context.fill();
// context.closePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменял код отрисовки:

```
function drawPlayer(player) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(player.positionX, player.positionY, player.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fillStyle = 'blue';
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();

  // Рисование лицевой части круга с учетом угла
  context.save();
  context.translate(player.positionX, player.positionY);
  context.rotate(player.angle);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, player.radius, -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
  context.restore();
}

function draw() {
  for (let id in players) {
      drawPlayer(players[id]);
  }
}
```